# No contexto Web o que é um proxy?

Tags: terminologia, proxy

Como se trabalha com essa tecnologia e qual seu uso no dia dia de uma aplicação web seja no caso do cliente ou do servidor ?

Casos de uso podem ser em qualquer linguagem, apenas para compreensão de seu funcionamento.

Answer (score 2):

Um proxy é um "intermediário" entre um cliente e um servidor.

Um caso de uso típico para proxy é o balanceamento de servidores. Vamos supor que um site tenha 10 servidores. No entanto, o site recebe os pedidos apenas por um proxy, que redireciona cada pedido recebido para um dos 10 servidores, de maneira que a carga de trabalho seja dividida igualmente entre os 10 servidores.

Um outro caso de uso é o proxy para cache. Neste caso, pedidos repetitivos e páginas estáticas como imagens, scripts, etc ficam na memória do proxy, e não em disco, para melhorar a performance de resposta. De maneira geral, apenas as páginas dinâmicas seriam repassadas para os servidores de backend.